What does it mean the MCU has 1 ADC and 10 ADC channels?
I got this AVR Microchip MCU ATtiny 204 chip. Now what I can't get, what do they mean in the datasheet it has 1 ADC and 10 channels ADC?
The datasheet:https://datasheet.octopart.com/ATTINY204-SSF-Microchip-datasheet-113117884.pdf
This is in page number 10:


Just a note - there are some applications where you really want to have multiple ADCs, one being energy metering (because the phase relationship of voltages and currents directly impacts energy and thus money).

@SpehroPefhany Can you please give an example for such a device?

@HazardousVoltage Energy/power metering was the given example. When measuring power in an AC system, it's critical that the voltage and current samples are taken simultaneously. Some loads (like capacitors and lightly-loaded motors) draw lots of current at full mains voltage, but because they have poor power factor, the actual power is small.

Rectifiers can be even worse, as the harmonics can cause really nasty waveforms that need very high sampling rates.

@SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica what about using energy meters?(I don't know if an ADC in integrated in it)

Energy meters, like a smart meter the power company uses to find out how much power you used. They measure the voltage and the current using ADCs.

It means that there is a single ADC responsible for performing the conversion, but the microcontroller also has a multiplexer, able to route any one of ten individual analogue signals to that single ADC, for conversion.
Consequently, if you you have ten signals to convert, each signal must be "routed", or "selected", connected to the ADC input, then converted, one after the other. If the ADC takes time \$t\$ to perform a single conversion, it will take at least time \$10t\$ to convert all ten signals. It wouldn't (necessarily) do that automatically. You must usually perform channel selection and initiate conversion yourself, programmatically.

Just making sure I understood you well. So it means that it  goes on cycles to convert the 10 signals like finish the first one then convert the second then the third and so on, right?

@HazardousVoltage Correct. Conversions must happen sequentially, one by one.

@HazardousVoltage:  generally you have to select the input channel to measure - the MCU will not normally scan all channels.  (although some MCUs may have that as an option.)

@PeterBennett I didn't mean to imply that it did, but it's worth adding.

There are also those that buffer the register settings, so you can start it converting, immediately cue another acquisition (channel and other settings), interrupt and save sample 0 while setting up sample 2, and so on until a series is complete or the sequence repeats. But, not to distract from the point -- indeed, there's always some way to do it, and "at least" 10t time is required (the buffering or auto-sequential case might do exactly 10t).

The ATTiny204 has one 10 bit ADC fed by a 10 input multiplexer.
The output of the ADC will be between 0 and 1023.
It can measure up to 10 different analog inputs, but only one input at a time. (You select an input, take a measurement, select another input, take another measurement, etc.)
Other members of that family have 6 or 12 ADC inputs.

Check out the overview of the ADC in section 29.2 (page 412), referencing how the ADC is hooked up to a 10-channel mux, providing up to 12 voltage inputs:

29.2 Overview
The Analog-to-Digital Converter (ADC) peripheral features a 10-bit
Successive Approximation ADC (SAR), with a sampling rate up to 115
ksps at 10-bit resolution (150 ksps at 8-bit). The ADC is connected to
a 10-channel analog multiplexer, which allows twelve single-ended
voltage inputs. The single-ended voltage inputs refer to 0V (GND). The
ADC input channel can either be internal (e.g. a voltage reference) or
external through the analog input pins.

For a more detailed description, Microchip also provides a "Getting Started with ADC" document that references the 204 and gives additional information about selecting the input channel:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/TB3209-Getting-Started-with-ADC-90003209A.pdf

The analog input channel is selected by writing to the MUXPOS bits in
the MUXPOS register (ADCn.MUXPOS). Any of the ADC input pins, GND,
internal Voltage Reference (VREF), or temperature sensor, can be
selected as single-ended input to the ADC. The ADC is enabled by
writing a ‘1’ to the ADC ENABLE bit in the Control A register
(ADCn.CTRLA). Voltage reference and input channel selections will not
go into effect before the ADC is enabled. The ADC does not consume
power when the ENABLE bit in ADCn.CTRLA is zero.


This refers to a single ADC converter with a multiplexer that allows one of several channels to be selected. Sometimes the channels include internal voltages such as a temperature sensor. It's quite normal to use fewer than the maximum number of channels available, often just one or two.
In some cases, such as energy monitoring and some types of precision instrumentation, we really want to have multiple actual ADC converters because the phase relationship of the analog inputs matters.
It's probably more common as of this writing (2024) to segregate such converters outside of the MCU chip, either as an ADC chip or an AFE (analog front end) chip that includes other useful functions.
But there are some that are integrated on the MCU, here is a Renesas chip that has 4 24-bit Delta-Sigma ADC converters on-chip: 

Thanks, got your idea.

Similarly for the STM32F373 with 3xDelta-Sigma 16 bit, and along with 1 SAR ADC. Number of channels for both DS and SAR varies with specific models
